# Making a readable plot in Seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

I am trying to make plot with Seaborn. My dataset contain two column with several thousand rows.

First column contain this values :

```
array(['62', '52', '10', '46', '23', '87', '64', '45', '69', '73', '82',
       '49', '11', '86', '47', '71', '61', '42', '29', '65', '21', '92',
       '24', '22', '99', '20', '68', '94', '12', '41', '85', '13', '30',
       '27', '35', '43', '74', '07', '84', '0', '02', '14', '08', '78',
       '93', '32', '26', '25', '96', '55', '66', '63', '17', '53', '50',
       '39', '70', '09', '01', '80', '38', '06', '58', '60', '81', '18',
       '33', '15', '95', '28', '59', '79', '77', '51', '56', '72', 0,
       ], dtype=object)
```

Second column contain this values:

```
array([1, 0], dtype=int64)
```

So my intention is to make plot in Seaborn and in order to do that I used this line of code and make plot like this

```
sns.swarmplot(x='customer',y='buy',data=dataset)
```

[image]

So value from X-axis are not good and can not be readied. So can anybody help me how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Is your data in the first column supposed to be discrete or continuous?

Comment: First column is type object or discrete

Comment: So, seeing as you want to keep every individual value marked on x-axis (correct me if I'm wrong), would scaling plot to be wider be an acceptable fix?

Comment: Well, it is what is is, right. All you are doing is plotting your data points. That's it. You could try to take the log, and plot that. Please see this link for more context. https://towardsdev.com/logarithmic-scale-how-to-plot-and-actually-understand-it-c38f00212206

Or, this.

https://dfrieds.com/data-visualizations/when-use-log-scale.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get back `ax` from your plot call, use `labels=ax.get_xticklabels()` to get them in order, and then
`ax.set_xticklabels(labels=labels,rotation=90)`
However, with thousands of points, readability would still be a challenge. If you can skip labels, you could replace them with empty strings except 1 in [how many makes it work].
Or maybe keep only those with 0-value as the others seem quite uniformly distributed. Only you know.
Of course resizing could also help.